# Authentication and aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple python script that I want to run as lambda function:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

get_last_modified = lambda obj: obj['SnapshotCreateTime'].timestamp()

rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
objs = rds_client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(DBClusterIdentifier='db-cluster')['DBClusterSnapshots']

print(objs)
```

Usually in linux I will have the .aws/config file that contains the auth key and token.
Where do add fill this values with lambda?

Comment: You will have to use IAM roles with the required permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use IAM role attached with lambda function to set a New/Update Policy.

1. Go to IAM
2. Go to Roles
3. Search and click on the IAM role associated with your lambda function
4. Either Update You old Policy or Attach one from the existing Policies
5. Save the changes.

Now you should be able to access the resource.

Note: If you are using IAM Roles with services, then you don't need to create any ACCESS_KEY or ACCESS_SECRET.

Answer (score 1):

To complement @Rahul's regarding **modify lambda execution role**, you also need to modify your code. It will not run on lambda in its current form.

Specifically, it requires a [lambda_handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html). For example:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

get_last_modified = lambda obj: obj['SnapshotCreateTime'].timestamp()
rds_client = boto3.client('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    objs = rds_client.describe_db_cluster_snapshots(DBClusterIdentifier='db-cluster')['DBClusterSnapshots']

    print(objs)
```